Momentarily load spike on MySQL
We have observed couple of load spike on MySQL instance daily on GCP.
Instance configuration :
DB version: MySQL 8.0.35
vCPUs: 12
Memory: 78 GB
SSD storage: 2.83 TB
Region: asia-southeast1-a

Error observed on spring-boot/java application whenever there's a load spike on CloudSQL instance.
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection;
nested exception is
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:277) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) at
org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) at
org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) at.invoke(SpringDataInstrumentationModule.java:112) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) at
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy255.findCartByUserIdAndType(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor574.invoke(Unknown Source) at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation153 moreCaused by:
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: cart_hikari_pool - Connection is not
available, request timed out after 1508ms. at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:689) at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196) at
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161) at
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100) at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) at
org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38) at
org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104) ... 191 more

At first we thought this is happening because we are short on mysql hikari pool on our application, so we plotted pool metrics, & saw we were wrong, idle pool size was enough & active connections never reached even idle pool size, set aside max pool size, as you can see in the image.

On application side we have below hikari properties set and config class.
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=85
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=cart_hikari_pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=1500
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=2000
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=***
spring.datasource.hikari.username=***
spring.datasource.hikari.password=***
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=40
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=1200000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=3600000

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.org.data.repo"}
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServiceDbConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig(){
        return new HikariConfig();
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = DatasourceConstants.DB.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.org.data.entities")
                .persistenceUnit("ServiceDB")
                .build();
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = DatasourceConstants.DB.TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier(DatasourceConstants.DB.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY) EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}

Cloud SQL system insights when we get Unable to acquire JDBC Connection exception.




In all of these spikes, most of the time query which takes maximum CPU is commit query and some get queries with left join operation performed (on max 25 rows), also seen latent at the same time.
I have looked into Logs Explorer for CloudSQL to understand what happens exactly during these spikes, and saw below pattern of queries whenever application gets 'JDBC Connection Exception'.

Queries were executing normally with <= 200-300ms time.
Some queries started executing slow. Reaches till from 1.5-2 seconds.
And then DB gives lots of error saying: 1506039 [Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Aborted connection 1506039 to db: 'cart' user: 'cart-rw' host: '-------' (Got an error reading communication packets).


Conclusion :

It seem DB is aborting the connections as soon as query starts getting latent, also there's no reason for query being latent as it's the same query running before as well, but it does get's latent and then the spike comes.
In MySQL queries graph above, it seems number of queries execution increases whenever the issue occurs, even though from the application metrics RPS is consistent with slight change (100-200).


Is there any other place we should look into to understand root cause of the problem fix it for good.


Your connection timeout is far too short at 1500ms. It should be in tens of seconds. 1000ms is also pretty short for a validation timeout.

Index computation?

@user207421, Should we really set 10s as connection timeout , let's say when idle connections get's filled up, pool will expand to max connections, but all the requests will timeout while pool is expanding, as SLA of service is 500ms, so eventually those extra connections would never setup or drop as they will remain unused. Also do you think this could be because of lower connection timeout, the pool we plot we saw that idle connection increased but never the active connections when spike happened.

Do you use BLOB columns or have data being read heavier? Seeing the error which is closer to communication packets issue, it could be that, maybe for now you can temporarily set max_allowed_packet in GCP cloud instance and see if the error is mitigated.

"Unable to acquire JDBC Connection" is a connection pool error, not a MySQL error. This problem is likely to be that there was a brief demand for more than 85 concurrent connections, and it failed. The problem with charts like you show is that a spike can occur very briefly, between the intervals, so it is never visible as a spike on the chart.

@NagarajTantri, we do have varbinary and size of that columns is small around 500Kb or less, & we have currently max_allowed_packet set as 33MB, which should be enough.

@BillKarwin, But why/how idle connection increase is seen going till almost max connection, around 84 or even 85 in some of the machines.

Also I am seeing increase in connection as an effect and not the cause, cause could be queries being slow first and then leading to more connections from app side.

@guillaumeblaquiere can you explain a bit more. We have the index on user_id based on which we fetch the primary entity - cart, and when we do it join to other table cart_items, here we have cart_id here (which acts as reference key) and that's also indexed on cart_items table. What am i missing !

The graph is not a continuous curve.

If the SLA is 500ms you should set the timeout to SLA plus two or three standard deviations, to capture the realistic range of possibilities while detecting genuine failures. The software doesn’t know what your SLA is. Here you clearly have too short a timeout in practice.

Understood. @user207421. I'll adjust timeouts & monitor for these spikes.Also can we say the real cause is connection/validation timeout being less, as this connection not aquire exception comes just after slow queries comes in DB logs, and we have seen this pattern almost always. What I am not able to understand is how query gets latent after all at first. Such that app tries to make more connections and the connections gets timeout.

My suggestions for digging deeper:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Rick, In your mysql_analysis request, please consider adding a line
How many cores in the server -  AFTER  How much RAM in the server.
There are many people ignoring the number of cores available when setting Global Variable requests.
